# PHP anonymous function in arrays, what's the syntax?

Tags: php, arrays, callback, anonymous-function

Can i define anonymous functions as array value? This is not working:

```
   $m = array(
        0 => array('condition' => function($v) { return intval($v)}),
        3 => array('condition' => function($v) { return trim($v) > 0})
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$m = array(
    0 => array('condition' => function($v) { return intval($v); }),
    3 => array('condition' => function($v) { return trim($v) > 0; }),
);
```

You forgot the **;**.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, every statement has to be terminated by a semicolon. Try this:

```
$m = array(
           0 => array('condition' => function($v) { return intval($v);   } ),
           3 => array('condition' => function($v) { return trim($v) > 0; } )
           );
```

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) for details.